# How find and remove specific line with next or previous lines in large text document

Tags: c#, string, indexing, line, large-files

I'm trying to figure out, how to remove specific string from large text document with 500 000 lines. Find line by content, but at the same time get current line index value in text document order, which  must not be disturbed, to remove next or previous line of found line, in other words find closest by index, to remove both for large document. Because any method I've tried with using `File.WriteAllLines` program hangs with such  size. I have active requesting to this file and seems like need to find some other way. For example file content is:

```
1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
4. line 4
5. line 5
```

and line to find and remove is:

```
string input = "line 3"
```

to get this result with removing of found line index and next line index + 1 of next line, if found line index number is odd:

```
line 1
line 2
line 5
```

and at the same time be able to remove found line index and index - 1  previous line, if found line index is even number for searching string:

```
string input = "line 4"
```

and result should be:

```
line 1
line 2
line 5
```

And to know if line is does not exist in the text document.

Write to the same single file.

Comment: I can't get when need to remove _index and index + 1_, when need to remove _index and index - 1_? And also what is your output? Save in 2 different files?

Comment: @Alex Hello, I want delete - 1 if index of current line is even number and + 1 if odd, and output, write to the same not two files

Comment: May you [edit] your question, and provide correct example? As index of _line 3_ is odd, and give another example for even line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process very large file, the you should use `FileStream` to avoid loading all of the contents into memory.

To meet your last requirement, you can read the lines two by two. It actually makes your code simpler.

```
var inputFileName = @"D:\test-input.txt";
var outputFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

var search = "line 4";

using (var strInp = File.Open(inputFileName, FileMode.Open))
using (var strOtp = File.Open(outputFileName, FileMode.Create))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(strInp))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(strOtp))
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        var lineOdd = reader.ReadLine();
        var lineEven = (string)null;
        if (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            lineEven = reader.ReadLine();

        if(lineOdd != search && lineEven != search)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(lineOdd);

            if(lineEven != null)
                writer.WriteLine(lineEven);
        }
    }    
}

// at this point, operation is sucessfull
// rename temp file with original one
File.Delete(inputFileName);
File.Move(outputFileName, inputFileName);
```

Comment: Hello, seems like it is useful, but not sure, how to write to the same file? I don't need new file for output

Comment: @TimR You can just write to temporary file, and if the operation is sucessfull, delete the original file, then rename the temporary file with original one. This approach is safer because if something wrong in the middle of processing, the original file is not changed yet.

Comment: yes this is a answer I guess, but as I was asked to explain, when I need to remove index and index + 1 and when need to remove index and index - 1, I've edit my question and in this case your answer does not fully meet the question, although this is quite enough for me, but seems like I can mark it as answer with last edit in my question

Comment: @TimR See my edit. Your last requirement actually makes the code simpler. You can read the lines two-by-two and if one of them match, you strip both odd and even line.

Comment: Yes now your answer matches to my question with last edit for 100% thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

Let the input file is `inputFile.txt` then you can use `File.ReadAllLines()` method to get all lines in that particular file. Then use `IndexOf()` method to find the index of specific line in that list, if it is not found means it will return `-1` then use `RemoveAt()` to remove the line at that particular index. Consider the code:

```
List<string> linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList(); // gives you list of lines
string input = "line 3";
int lineIndex = linesInFile.IndexOf(input);
if (lineIndex != -1)
{
    linesInFile.RemoveAt(lineIndex);
}

// If you may have more number of match for particular line means you can try this as well :

linesInFile.RemoveAll(x=> x== input);
```

If you want to write it back to the file means use this line:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath,linesInFile);
```

Comment: Hello, as I realized, here I only need to specify the path to the file. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it does not removes any line

Comment: WE have not write it back to the file, use `File.WriteAllLines(filePath,linesInFile);` write it to the file, see the updates

Comment: well I've tried and seems like it should work, but can't get what is wrong, it still does not removes

Answer (score 0):

Use a [System.IO.StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private static void RemoveLines(string lineToRemove, bool skipPrevious, bool skipNext)
{
            string previousLine = string.Empty;
            string currentLine;
            bool isNext = false;
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"output.txt"))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"input.txt"))
                {

                    while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (isNext)
                        {
                            currentLine = string.Empty;
                            isNext = false;
                        }

                        if (currentLine == lineToRemove)
                        {
                            if (skipPrevious)
                            {
                                previousLine = string.Empty;
                            }

                            if (skipNext)
                            {
                                currentLine = string.Empty;
                                isNext = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (previousLine != string.Empty && previousLine != lineToRemove)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(previousLine);
                        }
                        previousLine = currentLine;
                    }
                }
                if (previousLine != string.Empty && previousLine != lineToRemove)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(previousLine);
                }
            }
}
```

Haven't tested it, but this would give required directions.

Comment: Hello, looks like it should work. but answer above, answers to my question fully, and also there was asked to  edit for complete explanation, so context was changed